# Getting a signal to a QListView when its populated by QComboBoxes

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyside

I'm working on a UI that reads a database and updates it back when items in it are changed. My UI consists of a QListView, and it's populated by QComboBoxes. Now, I can get a signal when a combo box item is changed (though I can't get the index of the widget item that was changed), and I need to let the parent list view know that a member widget's value had changed. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hack for obtaining the widget index is to code the widget index into the item data of each combo box item. You could set a QString as itemData which codes a reference to your standard item data and the widget index, e.g.

```
pComboBox1->setItemText(1, "Item 1");
pComboBox1->setItemData(1, "1-1"); 
pComboBox1->setItemData(2, "Item 2");
pComboBox1->setItemData(2, "2-1"); // Item 2 in 1st combo box
pComboBox2->setItemText(1, "Item 1");
pComboBox2->setItemData(1, "1-2"); // Item 1 in 2nd combo box
// and so on
```

Comment: Yes, this is what we ended up doing, though we used the pointer to the object for the item data. Thanks!